# Problem with PNG Fix for 2 overlapping images

Tags: jquery, drupal, internet-explorer, iepngfix

Hi I am using PNG FIx module in Drupal for 2 overlapping images on which I have applied some jquery effect. The Problem is that when I use the PNG fix module then in IE I start seeing 2 images placed side by side instead of overlapping each other.

Is there any solution to this problem ? Please Suggest. Thanks

Comment: I know what the problem is: IE! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the images are `background-image`s with custom `background-position`s, that may be the issue. Most PNG fix solutions don't handle `background-position` and `background-repeat` at all, and many that do have difficulties with them.

Comment: Thanks fr your answer. Finally I resolved the problem by replacing the png with a jpg. This might be a quick fix kind of a solution but wrkd fr me..

Answer (score 0):

This solution support background-image and position http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/